# Returning data using Return pattern

Tags: knockout.js

In my code below, how do I return the data from the `my.Author` function to the page, I know I'm missing something here. This is a stripped down vm. I want to keep this basic structure if possible.

In the console I can see 'my.Author' is receiving a value, but nothing prints out to the page.

```
 my.Author = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.authorid = ko.observable();
    self.authorname = ko.observable();
    self.authorprofile = ko.observable();
    self.gotoUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        return goToAuthor + self.authorid();
    }, self);
    self.gotoAuthorEditUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        return goToAuthorEdit + self.authorid();
    }, self);
};

my.vm = (function () {

    loadAuthorCallback = function (data) {

         my.Author.authorname = data.AuthorName;
         my.Author.authorid =   data.AuthorId;
         my.Author.authorprofile = data.AuthorProfile;

      },
    loadAuthor = function () {
         my.DataService.getAuthor(my.vm.loadAuthorCallback);
     };

return {    
        Author: my.Author(),
        loadAuthorCallback: loadAuthorCallback,
        loadAuthor: loadAuthor
      };

})();

my.vm.loadAuthor();

ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

Thanks & Regards
Melt

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the return pattern is?

Comment: The problem is `Author: my.Author()`. You either want "new" or you want to drop the `()`. Each scenario is working for me on a simple test using `<div data-bind="text: $root.Author.authorid "></div>`